# RFID Array Parameter to Python

Tags: python, arrays, arduino, raspberry-pi, rfid

We want to implement a chessboard, where RFID reader send the information, which square is being lifted up. Normally we are getting an array from the Arduiner (RFID Reader)

```
[['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'],
['bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp'],
['--', '--', '--', 'wQ', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp'],
['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']]
```

about every second. And when a figure gets lifted up, the Reader send us a matrix, where the Spot is empty. For example when a white pawn gets lifted up:

```
[['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'],
['bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp'],
['--', '--', '--', 'wQ', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', '--', 'wp', 'wp'],
['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']]
```

does anyone has an idea how we could extract the information from these two arrays, that this one square (F2, or row/col etc.) has been selected in Python or Arduino?

Answer (score 0):

The numpy module offers an extremely readable way to do so (commented inline):

```py
import numpy as np

old_array = np.array([['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'],
['bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp'],
['--', '--', '--', 'wQ', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp'],
['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']])

new_array = np.array([['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'],
['bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp'],
['--', '--', '--', 'wQ', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', '--', 'wp', 'wp'],
['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']])

# Array containing True iff there was a change between
# old_array and new_array
bool_array = old_array != new_array

# Tuple containing ([array of changed y coords], [array of changed x coords])
print(np.nonzero(bool_array))
```